# How compare two strings in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I need compare two strings while expression evaluation, but when I use it to CLIPSDOS it give wrong result.

```
CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> = 'AA' 'BA'
=
CLIPS>
```

Is CLIPS library support string comparison operation

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator is for numbers. For strings you need to use `eq`.

You also need to wrap the call between parenthesis to represent it as a function call.

```
In [1]: (eq 'AA' 'BA')                                                                                                                                                                                             
FALSE
```